# Try to access Request Form Post data from ActionFilterAttribute throw A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, http-post, request.form

I have implemented custom `ActionFilterAttribute` to create custom web access log and `OnActionExecuted` I try to access `ActionExecutedContext.HttpContext.Request.Form`collection using `Request.Form.GetValues("key")` i get this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (Aplications[0].Name="...."

because in my submitted form inputs contains HTML code.

I don't want to disable some .net MVC integrated security using `validateRequest="false"` and also I can't set to all my input or actions `[AllowHtml]` or `ValidateInput(false)` because my action filter catch all my controllers.

I found a hack solution but is no other option?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream))
{
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var inputsNameValueCollection = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(content).Split('&');
    foreach (string input in inputsNameValueCollection)
    {
        var inputNameValue = input.Split('=');
        var inputName = nameValue[0];
        var inputValue = nameValue[1];
    }
}
```